# iOS UI Automation : toggle network settings during test execution time from within the tests

Tags: ios, networking, automation, disconnect

I need to test various alerts that comes when network disconnects at various points of test flows. So I need to disconnect iPad/simulator from network. Is there any way where we can toggle network settings during tests execution time from within the tests ?

I have searched and found it is not possible : [Is it possible to disable the network in iOS Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808433/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-network-in-ios-simulator)
But, the response here is old , wondering do we have some approach now ?

Answer (score 1):

Using function `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` on `UIAHost` you can run any program on your computer (if you know the absolute path).

If you can write a program or script (e.g. using osascript) which will turn your internet connection off, then it's possible.

I am actually using this function to open a web page in the simulator which redirects to a link handled by my application, thus testing the behavior when the application is opened from the browser.