# How do I test notifications of Reachability changes in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, testing, reachability

I know [that there are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835753/590767) to control the iOS simulator's connection (which actually is just the underlying host Mac OS X system connection) to the internet.

I specifically want to test [receiving and processing of reachability change notifications](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability#nsnotification-example) on the simulator. You can imagine that doing this on the device is somewhat more painful.

I found that using `Network Link Conditioner` tool to cause a 100% loss doesn't emit anything to the Notification Center, even though I would expect it to.

Has anyone found a way to trigger the notification on the simulator?