# Test network problems via UI Automation

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation

Is there a way to simulate (and therefore test) network outages via UI Automation?

I’m aware of the Network Link Conditioner tool (and have read this [Is it possible to disable the network in iOS Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808433/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-network-in-ios-simulator)) but this requires me to manually set it up and I was hoping for a way to somehow launch the equivalent of the Network Link Conditioner from a UI Automation test.

Comment: This is more of a [testing](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question than a [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) one. Alternatively, it could also be regarded as a [software recommendation request](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES and NO depending on how you want to run/setup your tests. For example, you can use the **Network Link Conditioner** on a local Mac. Just share the network connection from the Mac and connect your iOS device to it. Then, manually change the network conditions on your Mac during your test runs or create an **AppleScript** to do it automatically.

Now, if you want to change the settings on your device and test the network conditions, it may not be possible without jailbreaking your device.