# Connectivity - How to Manually / Programmatically Set IsConnected Property to False

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, connectivity

In the Xamarin plugin [Connectivity (Xam.Plugin.Connectivity)](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin), there is an easy way from the PCL to detect network connectivity changes, like:

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    page.DisplayAlert("Connectivity Changed", "IsConnected: " + args.IsConnected.ToString(), "OK");
};
```

The property `IsConnected` is read only, so my question is:

**Is there a way to manually / programmatically set `IsConnected` to false or otherwise simulate a lost network connection?**

Comment: use airplane mode

Comment: @Jason - I'm using an emulator and I can't set airplane mode, unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808433/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-network-in-ios-simulator

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to programmatically simulate a missing network connection. You can obviously do other things in the simulator and on real devices to achieve what you are looking for. I am not sure what the use case is here, but you could try using something like

`CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("TestHostname", 80, 1000)`

rather than relying on the IsConnected property which, as you said is read-only.
If you want the user to be "disconnected", hand the method a an invalid hostname, if you want them to be "connected" hand it something valid.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a MockConnectivity:

```
using Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions;

namespace MyMockConnectivity
{
  public class MockConnectivity : BaseConnectivity
  {
    public void SetIsConnected(bool value)
    {
        OnConnectivityChanged(new ConnectivityChangedEventArgs { IsConnected = value });
    }

    public override bool IsConnected { get; }
...
```

Use:

```
using MyMockConnectivity;
using Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions;
...
MockConnectivity MockConnectivity = new MockConnectivity();
IConnectivity Current = MockConnectivity;

Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
  Debug.WriteLine("IsConnected: " + args.IsConnected);
};
```

Simulate connectivity changes:

```
// Simulate network connection
MockConnectivity.SetIsConnected(true);

// Simulate lost network connection
MockConnectivity.SetIsConnected(false);
```